# Как сделать так что бы программа по конвертации массива картинок заработала?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SomeFolder", "*.JPG", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            Bitmap[] bmpArr = new Bitmap[files.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < bmpArr.Length; i++)
            {
                bmpArr[i] = new Bitmap(files[i]);
            }

            Image RotateImage(Bitmap[] bmpArr)
            {
                var img = new Bitmap(bmpArr);

                // using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmpArr))
                // {
                //     gfx.Clear(Color.White);
                //     gfx.DrawBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
                // }

                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                return img;
            }
            RotateImage(bmpArr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы ваш вопрос стал более понятным?

Comment: я сделал папку, в которой находятся картинки формата Jpg, я беру эти картинки и перебираю в помошью цикла, далее я пытаюсь повернуть все картинки на 90 градусов, по аргументу, но вознакает ошибка, пробовал так и так разные ошибки и исключения, а сути не понимаю от чего надо отталкиваться

Comment: [C# rotate bitmap 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2225363/312041)

Answer (score 3):

Просто проходим циклом по файлам, создаём объект `Bitmap` и поворачиваем изображение вызовом метода `RotateFlip`.

Методом `Save` повёрнутое изображение сохраняется. В данном случае по тому же пути, то есть старое изображение затрётся. Измените путь при необходимости.

Если для какой-то цели нужен массив, то раскомментируйте строки с ним.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SomeFolder", "*.JPG", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[files.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(files[i]);
    bitmaps[i] = bitmap;
    bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    bitmap.Save(files[i]);
}
```

Если объекты Bitmap в дальнейшем не нужны для какой-либо цели, то нет смысла помещать их в массив. И нужно освободить занимаемые ими ресурсы.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SomeFolder", "*.JPG", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(files[i]))
    {
        bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        bitmap.Save(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!)

Comment: И тоже using посеял...

Comment: @Qwertiy - Я думал про using, но изначально у автора битмапы помещаются в массив. Значит диспозить их не надо. | Обновил

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Image image in Directory
    .GetFiles(@"C:\SomeFolder", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(Bitmap.FromFile))
{
    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    image.Save("какая то ссылка дериктории");
};
```

Comment: Не делайте строки длинными - эту будет сильно мешать смотреть диффы при мёржах в системах контроля версий. И просто так принято.

Comment: понял, возьму к сведению!) благодарю

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не будет.

Comment: Надо бы using присобачить...